# How to retrieve the word in an EditText or ViewText on an ontouch event in an android application

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a an application with an EditText that have some text in it.
I want to create an event that retrieves the word that I touch in the EditText component.
How do I do that?

thanks in advance

kobi

Answer (score 1):

you can get the `selected word` from your edit text..

```
String text=yourEditText.getText().toString();
String slectedWord=text.subSequence(yourEditText.getSelectionStart(), yourEditText.getSelectionEnd());
```